# SVN pre-commit hooks for YAML and XML validation

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I've Been asked to check for XML and YAML files syntax during the commit process, basically the task is that whenever a developer commit contains yaml or xml files, svn **pre-commit hook** needs to run a check wether they're valid (syntax and format wise).

I know that on the **svn server** side, we have **hooks** directory that contains all the hooks, and in order to activate one of them we just need to eliminate the **.tmpl** extension so it could run whenever an attempt to commit changes to remote repository is taking place.

What I can't find is the hook's logic (code) of detecting the XML, YAML files being committed and validating them so the commit could pass.

Down below is the default content of pre-commit hook file that's supposedly will need some more logic of knowing which file is which and then check wether they're ok or not.

**pre-commit.tmpl**

```
 REPOS="$1"
 TXN="$2"

 # Make sure that the log message contains some text.
 SVNLOOK=/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1_4/bin/svnlook
 $SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
 grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1

 # Check that the author of this commit has the rights to perform
 # the commit on the files and directories being modified.
 commit-access-control.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN" commit-access-control.cfg || exit 1

 # All checks passed, so allow the commit.
 exit 0
```

The script above needs more code for detecting xml and yaml files + syntax validation logic. SVNLOOK needs to pass a list of files edited or added in a commit so we could do check them by the python command.

This is linux command line that I think could go inside the **pre-commit** hook script

```
python -c 'import yaml, sys; yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)' < cfg.yaml.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not related to git. Removing tag

Comment: This template is just an example of things you can do, not a ready to use script for all use cases. You can get a list of changed files with `svnlook changed`, which you'll need to loop in search for XML and YAML files. For that you'll need some shell or Python scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python script this is pretty simple. Here is a template for python script that you can use. Just replace the comment with your check and based on status you can either reject the commit or accept it.

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_output
import re
import yaml

def check_fileType(changed_list):
    """Perform File Type Check here
    """
    error = 0
    stream = sys.stderr # Use this stream if you want to debug
    for path in changed_list:
        match = re.search(r".yaml$",path)
        if match:
            # Do YAML Check here for each path
            # if YAML Check fails set error to 1
            # if no YAML error then 0 will be returned
            error = 1
    return error;
def run(argv):
    repo = argv[1]
    tranx = argv[2]
    cmd = ('svnlook','changed',repo,'-t',tranx)
    out = check_output(cmd)
    changed_paths = [ line[4:] for line in out.split('\n') if len(line) > 4 ]
    status = check_fileType(changed_paths)
    if status:
        sys.exit(1) # Non zero exit indicates error
```